# Go: dial tcp: lookup tcp/8080/ping: getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found

Tags: golang, http

Есть http-сервер на локалхосте. Он раз в минуту пингуется такой командой:

```go
conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", "localhost:80/ping", time.Minute)
```

Возникала такая ошибка:

```
dial tcp: lookup tcp/80/ping: getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found.
```

Решил попробовать попинговать гугл. Команда стала выглядеть так:

```go
conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", "google.com:80/images", time.Minute)
```

Получал такую же ошибку, но с другим адресом:

```go
dial tcp: lookup tcp/80/images: getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found.
```

с самим же гуглом, т.е. с "google.com", но там возникают проблемы с `ioutil.ReadAll(conn), а именно — оно там зависает.

Версия: 1.17.6

Answer (score 0):

Блин, почему всегда после того, как написал вопрос на стаковерфлоу после нескольких часов мучений, сам находишь ответ)

1. я ж всё же по http обращаюсь, надо писать ещё заголовки, что хочу; tcp же только подключается
2. просто стал делать http.Get()